# Group By SAS - Selecting Multiple Obs

Tags: sql, date, sas, proc

I'm trying to select the all of the most recent date from the group of observations below

Full Data

```
  ID    Date <br/>

   1    02/01/2015 <br/>
   1    02/01/2015 <br/>
   1    02/01/2015 <br/>
   1    01/01/2015 <br/>
   1    01/01/2015 <br/>
   1    01/01/2015 <br/>

   2    04/01/2014 <br/>
   2    04/01/2014 <br/>
   2    04/01/2014 <br/>
   2    05/01/2014 <br/>
   2    05/01/2014 <br/>
   2    05/01/2014 <br/>
```

I've tried IF.FIRST & LAST etc.. however I just keeping getting the very first obs Eg....

Wrong Data

```
  ID    Date  <br/>

   1    02/01/2015 <br/>
   2    04/01/2014 <br/>
```

What I'm after is...

Subset Data

```
      ID    Date  <br/>

       1    02/01/2015 <br/>
       1    02/01/2015 <br/>
       1    02/01/2015 <br/>
       2    04/01/2014 <br/>
       2    04/01/2014 <br/>
       2    04/01/2014 <br/>
```

Hope someone can help! 
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution might work with what you already got. Take your WrongData and merge with your FullData to get the desired output.

```
data Want;
merge FullData WrongData (in=A);
by id date;
if A;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `proc sql`.  The SQL statement is:

```
select t.*
from fulldata t
where t.date = (select max(t2.date) from fulldata t2);
```

EDIT:

If you want the max date per `id`, just use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from fulldata t
where t.date = (select max(t2.date) from fulldata t2 where t2.id = t.id);
```

Comment: Many thanks - This code is getting close - Is it possible to include some sort of group by so it would be the max date per ID? I have adjusted the example above to show this - Many thanks in advance!